# Custom AuthenticationFailureHandler is not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Registered handler in security configuration:

```java
.formLogin().loginPage(/login).failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
```

My custom failure handler:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private String failureUrl="/login?error";

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, this.failureUrl);
    }

}
```

`onAuthenticationFailure` is getting triggered when auth failures happen but along with that one more request is also triggering by Spring, please find the another req stack,

```
LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, AuthenticationException) line: 169   
ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain, AuthenticationException) line: 204 
ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain, RuntimeException) line: 178
```

So this request is overriding my sendredirect request.

Should I need to configure/do anything else to achieve this ? Please help on this. 
Thanks in advance

My configuration:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(SignUpFilter(userService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/register",
                        "/retrieveUsernameForm",
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
            .anonymous()
                .authenticationProvider(anonymousAuthenticationProvider())
                .authenticationFilter(anonymousAuthenticationFilter())
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                     .loginPage(SecurityController.URI_LOGIN)
                     .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl(securityController.createUri(SecurityController.PATH_PART_LOGIN))
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .key(REMEMBERME_TOKEN_KEY)
                .rememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeServices())
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .headers()
                    .frameOptions().disable()
                    .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN"))
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();

        http.formLogin()
                .addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter>() {
                    @Override
                    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter postProcess(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter) {
                        filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategyForContentAndStoreUsers());
                        return filter;
                    }
                });

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
    }
```

Comment: "localhost:8080/test/login"  and if error is handled in handler, i am appending /login?error and as i mentioned in the body the 2nd request is overriding and the url is becoming localhost:8080/test/login. so i cant catch error scenario in my controller.

Comment: SecurityController.URI_LOGIN = "/login" (contains context + login) and SecurityController.PATH_PART_LO‌​GIN is "/login"

Comment: You have to allow the access to your failure URL. Add  `login` to `.antMatchers("/", "/register","/retrieveUsernameForm"`.

Comment: its working now. thanks a lot. and pls tell me, if we mentioned any uri in .antMatchers("") that spring will not interfere ? in this flow if any failures happen in /login url I have to carry the flow through my handler?

Comment: Glad to help you, but I don't understand your question in your comment. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: if I mention /login uri in .antMatchers("/login") like this then the spring default security request will not interfere with my uri ? here if any failures happen in /login url I have to say where the url should go and define the flow ?